Transcribing an ancient document
Edit: I now have a complete Chinese text edited by Yanagida and a translation into Japanese by Cheng.
I wonder if anyone has the time and enthusiasm to transcribe the handwriting on this document? https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b83026045/f1.highres

This image shows the whole of what's left, part of a 7th century commentary on the Heart Sutra that was part of the cache of texts found at Dunhuang (now in the Bibliotheque Nationale de France: Catalogue no. Pelliot Chinois 4940).
This is one of the oldest commentaries but to my knowledge this text has never been studied in the English-speaking world (there are three other damage manuscripts). As far as I know there are no published transcriptions, so the aim would to publish (eventually). Trouble is, I can't read handwritten Chinese very well, so I'm hoping to crowdsource a transcription.
The posted image is probably not very clear, but there is a good hi res version if you follow the link.

is there any deadline? i might do it when i’ve time

Buddhas know no time: take your time! I would like a copy too, please!

@Pedroski, life is short, particularly for an aged lunatic

No deadline. But you've already solved it!

variant characters not yet “corrected”
般若波羅蜜多心經䟽 資州詵禪師ｘ
夫以真宗冲ｘ妙絕名詮之表正覺ｘｘｘｘ像累之外將求性
相二有不能照其機跡ｘ淺深三ｘ无以臻其極耳色非色寄
无色以為源耳空非空要假空而遣色故知万靈无像而无眾
像之宗妙理无言抑乃群言而為本蓋像出於無像言出於
take a break now, stay tuned 
well, i found that there’s a japanese pdf contained the above text (most likely):
http://repo.komazawa-u.ac.jp/opac/repository/all/29143/jbk065-03.pdf
ok, some characters, i disagreed with the linked pdf 
here’s the associated screenshots:




This is brilliant. Thank you so much.

The text of the commentary is in Part One of the 3-part article. This isn't online with the other parts, but I can get it from the library.
http://repo.komazawa-u.ac.jp/opac/repository/all/search/simple/?lang=1&mode=0&kywd=%E6%99%BA%E8%A9%B5%E6%92%B0

@Jayarava , there’re significant difference between the pelliot chinois 4940 & 駒澤大學‘s pdf  故知万靈无像・而无眾像之宗・妙理无言・抑乃群言而為本 vs 故知万靈无像・而爲眾像之宗・妙理无言・抑乃群言之本. semantically, the verse of the pdf is more “smooth / natural”; imo

Yeah. He's translating from an edition created in 1972 by Yanagida based on four manuscripts from Dunhuang. I'm hoping to get hold of this also to get the variant readings. Thanks again.

I have now posted the Chinese text with a translation into Japanese on my academia page: https://www.academia.edu/120669748/Zh%C3%ACsh%C4%93ns_%E6%99%BA%E8%A9%B5_Commentary_on_the_Heart_Sutra
